# Batch issue for my control program

Tags: batch-file

I keep having issues with my BATCH script but I can't figure out what it is. 
Now it says "syntax error"
If you fix the script, I will give you the download for the control software this is for.
Here is my Script:

```
@echo off
echo welcome to Nexus
echo loading project file
pause
if exist C:\nexus\nexus\proj

\nexus.nexus 
echo Loaded!
echo Settings:
>nul find "-f" nexus.nexus && (
  echo -f
call -f.bat
) || (
echo errortest)
>nul find "-c" nexus.nexus && (
  echo -c
call -c.bat
) || (
echo errortest)
>nul find "-e" nexus.nexus && (
  echo -e
call -e.bat
) || (
echo errortest)
>nul find "-b" nexus.nexus && (
  echo -b
call -b.bat
) || (
echo errortest)
>nul find "-nex" nexus.nexus && (
  echo -nex
call -nex.bat
) || (
echo errortest)
>nul find "-nexdev" nexus.nexus 

&& (
  echo -nexdev
call -nexd.bat
) || (
echo errortest)
) else (
    echo ERROR:FILE 

NONEXISTENT
echo exiting
exit
)
echo project complete
pause
echo exiting
exit
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: it keeps telling me there is an unexpected character.

Comment: You can't use an empty code block as in `|| ()`. Note that a new line `CRLF` is still considered empty.

Comment: now it says "incorrect syntax of command" despite fixing it.

Comment: if it tells you "incorrect syntay", it also tells you which line it has problems with.

Comment: It didn't show me the line.

Comment: Reminder: if you fix the script, you will receive THE FIRST COPY of the software when ready. The software version will be 0.0.9  .

Comment: Have you got a copy&paste error? There are extraneous newlines in your "if exists" command.

Comment: I'll get rid of the "if exists"

Comment: OMG THANK YOU SO MUCH IT WORKED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!